# Python, al iterar sobre los elementos de una lista, muestra elementos difrentes

Tags: python, python-3.x

soy nuevo en esto y estoy haciendo un programa en python que pase un número decimal a hexadecimal. Como ustedes sabrán, hay un método que consiste en pasar de decimal a binario y de binario a hexadecimal (agrupando los bits de cuatro en cuatro, de derecha a izquierda y mirando luego en la tabla a qué número corresponde cada grupo de bits). Yo he escogido ese método para traducirlo al algoritmo del programa. He conseguido que primero pase el número decimal a binario y que cada bit lo ponga en una misma lista. Ahora tocaría agrupar de cuatro en cuatro cada bit de derecha a izquierda. El problema es que, si la longitud de la lista > 4, el programa al iterar sobre cada elemento de la lista y al añadírselo a otra lista, el output muestra un numero diferente, no sé si me explico.

```
bin_hex_dict = {
    '0000' : '0',
    '0001' : '1',
    '0010' : '2',
    '0011' : '3',
    '0100' : '4',
    '0101' : '5',
    '0110' : '6',
    '0111' : '7',
    '1000' : '8',
    '1001' : '9',
    '1010' : 'A',
    '1011' : 'B',
    '1100' : 'C',
    '1101' : 'D',
    '1110' : 'E',
    '1111' : 'F', 
}

num = input("Introduzca un numero decimal para pasarlo a hexadecimal: ")
potencias = []
binary_num = []
binary_num_def = []
binary_num_def2 = []
binary_num_def_matrix = []

while True:
    potencias =  [2**x for x in range(int(num), -1, -1)]
    for y in potencias:
        if int(num)-y<0:
            binary_num.append(0)
            finish = True            
        else:
            binary_num.append(1)
            num = int(num) - y
            finish = True
    if finish:
        break
    
print(binary_num)

for x in range(0, len(binary_num)):
    if binary_num[x] == 1:
        for y in binary_num[0:x]:
            binary_num.remove(binary_num[y])
        break                   

print(binary_num)

times = 0

if len(binary_num) ==  4:
    for x in range(len(binary_num)-1, -1, -1):
        binary_num_def.insert(0, binary_num[x])
    binary_num_def_matrix.insert(0, binary_num_def)
elif len(binary_num) < 4:
    for x in range(len(binary_num)-1, -1, -1):
        binary_num_def.insert(0, binary_num[x])
    binary_num_def_matrix.insert(0, binary_num_def)
else:
    for x in range(len(binary_num)//4):
        if times == 4:
            for y in range(len(binary_num)-times-1, len(binary_num)-times-5, -1):
                print(f'y : {y}')
                print(f'binary_num[y]: {binary_num[y]}')
                binary_num_def2.insert(0, binary_num[y])
                print(f'binary_num_def2 : {binary_num_def2}')
                binary_num.remove(binary_num[y])
            binary_num_def_matrix.insert(0, binary_num_def2)
        elif times < 4:
            for y in range(len(binary_num)-1, len(binary_num)-5, -1):
                print(f'y: {y}')
                print(f'binary_num[y]: {binary_num[y]}')
                binary_num_def.insert(0, binary_num[y])
                print(f'binary_num_def : {binary_num_def}')
                binary_num.remove(binary_num[y])
                times += 1
            binary_num_def_matrix.insert(0, binary_num_def)   
    binary_num_def_matrix.insert(0, binary_num) 

print(binary_num_def_matrix)
print(binary_num)
```

Al ejecutar el código y poner el número 10010 (decimal) sale esto en pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero saber es por qué me sale que binary_num[y] es un número diferente del número que debería ser.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: `hexa = f"{num:04x}"` es todo lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Te complicas mucho la vida.

```
num = 100010
hexa = []
while num:
    digito = num % 16
    hexa.append("0123456789ABCEDF"[digito])
    num = num >> 4
valor = ''.join(hexa[::-1])
print(valor)
```

La idea es iterar hasta que `num` desaparezca. En cada iteración extraemos los cuatro últimos bits de `num`; eso es lo que se obtiene al calcular el resto de `num % 16`. Esos cuatro bits los transformamos a hexadecimal usandolo como indice del string:

```
hexa.append("0123456789ABCEDF"[digito])
```

También tenemos que reducir `num`, eliminado los cuatro últimos dígitos. Eso se hace con un `shift` a la derecha por cuatro bits:

```
num = num >> 4
```

Al terminar la iteración tenemos una lista de digitos hexadecimales en el orden inverso. Usamos `[::-1]` para invertir la lista y luego juntamos todos los caracteres.

**Método alternativo**

También puedes hacer

```
valor = f"{num:x}"
```

para llegar a lo mismo.